# Getting a background image to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a background image to change when hovered over. This part I have working, but for some reason the new image appears in a different location. I also have no idea to get the normal image to go away when hovered over. I created two different images to get the effect I am going after. I am unsure if this is the correct method, but it was all I could think of. Also, for some reason I cannot get the `cursor:pointer;` to work with the `background-image.

How can I get the hover image to be in the same spot as the original image and either cover it completely, so the initial one does not show, or remove the first one until not hovered over.

```css
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
#home-arrow {
  /*height: 100px;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 99;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
#circle-arrow {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 155px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
#home-arrow:hover {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 155px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <div id="home-arrow">
    <div id="circle-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `#circle-arrow` after `#home-arrow:hover` selector in your css, and just add hover image for the background, it will work for you.

```
#home-arrow:hover #circle-arrow{
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
}
```

**Edit 1** (hover only on circle)

If you want to get hover only on circle then just remove `#home-arrow:hover` and replace it with `#circle-arrow:hover` as

```
#circle-arrow:hover{
        background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
    }
```

and if you crop your images to just about width of the circle then it will be good for circle hover. Right Now both images have lots of empty space on left and right.

**EDIT 2** (some issue with z-index)
Add `background-position:center` to your `#home-arrow:hover` and remove width, height etc as:

```
#home-arrow:hover {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center; 
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

[**See Updated Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/qwf8vju4/4/)

Comment: so you want to hover on the circle only ?

Comment: It doesn't hover when I just do `#circle-arrow:hover{
        background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
    }`

Comment: remove `z-index` from your `#home-arrow` css it will work

Comment: @Paul add `background-position: center;` and remove width, height etc, see updated answer.

Comment: @Paul it will allow you to use your z-index as well.

Comment: That allows me to see the hover again, but the white circle appears over it... If you go to my page, you can see it only hovers in the `home-arrow` section. For some reason, nothing is happening within the `circle-arrow` div.

Comment: I'm not saying that's the issue. It is that it still doesn't hover.

Comment: I know that, but someone isn't going to try to select that from the far left or right. Nothing works for the `circle-arrow` div. Not a `cursoir:pointer` the hover. I don't know why.

Comment: @Paul it works if you increase z-index to 999 for #home-arrow

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you for the extended help and working with me on this. Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that for #home-arrow, the position is absolute. For #home-arrow:hover, the position is relative. That might cause a problem.

Comment: The solution in this case would make the #home-arrow:hover match #home-arrow for the position attribute. Usually, for a :hover, I only include attributes that are different than the same class without the :hover.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting  `#circle-arrow:hover` selector for `#home-arrow:hover`

```css
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
#home-arrow {
  /*height: 100px;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 99;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
#circle-arrow {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 155px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
#circle-arrow:hover {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 155px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <div id="home-arrow">
    <div id="circle-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see it works on your snippet, but it doesn't hover at all on my actual page.

Comment: @Paul _"I see it works on your snippet, but it doesn't hover at all on my actual page."_ Can you create a plnk http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: _"What does plnkr.co even do?"_ Allows saving and displaying `html` , `css`, `js` http://plnkr.co/edit/UwkeMciZYuOpdxobKKe5?p=preview

Comment: @Paul Note, `html` at Question appear different from `html` at linked page; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does that matter? The ids are exactly as they are in my real page. I added a background div because the arrow is white. My question is completely straight forward. Why would I put additional items in my question other than what the issue is.

Comment: _"Why would I put additional items in my question other than what the issue is."_  `.circle` element appear displayed over `#circle-arrow` element at linked page with `position` property set to `absolute` ; `.circle` element does not appear at Question

Comment: Right...without the z-index. I changed it back.

Comment: All included `html` , `css` that would affect display should be included at actual Question at SO, to correctly reproduce issue.

Comment: All of the relevant info is included in the question. What are you talking about? The z-index is in my question.

Comment: All of the relevant info does not appear included in the Question. Else, approach described at above Answer would resolve Question ? See initial comment to above Answer at  _"I see it works on your snippet, but it doesn't hover at all on my actual page."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376539/getting-a-background-image-to-hover/35376565#comment58458748_35376565

Comment: I don't know what is causing that to not work though. Why else would I have posted this question??? I tried your solution first and it didn't work, so I tried my original solution and it showed up, just not where I wanted it. If I knew what was causing it, I wouldn't have wasted the last 45 minutes on here.

Comment: @Paul Not a waste; fwiw only attempting to convey that including all actual `html` , `css` at Question would, possibly, help users that provide answers who may not have read comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376539/getting-a-background-image-to-hover/35376565#comment58458788_35376565 _"The actual page is optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index"_ with closest representation of `html` , `css`

Answer (score 0):

Change your class "#home-arrow:hover" by

```
#home-arrow:hover {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 195px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  background-position: 0 78px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace `#home-arrow:hover` in the css with `#circle-arrow:hover`.

Then you can do some pruning of the css...

```
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
#home-arrow {
  /*height: 100px;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 99;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
#circle-arrow {
  background: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow.png") no-repeat center center;
  height: 155px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
#circle-arrow:hover {
  background: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow-hover.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Note I changed the height of `#blue` selector and the `top` property of `#home-arrow` so it can be seen in a [**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/trv2uqkc/)...

The `#circle-arrow` and `#circle-arrow:hover` are the two selectors you should be able to just copy/paste into your css.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the hovering issues with the background image...

```
cursor: default;
```